# Git merge behaviour - give me the conflict tags

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a Git-expert, who know how to reconfigure Git to allow me to do a git pull - even if there are merge conflicts?

I have no problem at all to manually rework merge problems with

```
<<<<<< STUFF
CRAP CODE version 1
=======
CRAP CODE version 2
>>>>> STUFF
```

Currently I get

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
theRestaurantAtTheEndOfTheUniverse.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 2):

"There are merge conflicts" implies there's already a merge in progress, and merge conflicts are the only things that require manual rework in the first place.  If you're trying to do a second merge on top of that, it can't be from the same branch as the one producing your current conflicts -- and the way to merge from multiple branches is to just merge from them all at once:

```
git remote update   # do all the fetching there is to do
git merge origin/master lucy/lamppost professor/sanitychecks edmund/turks
```

Answer (score 0):

The best trick I have is to do

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
git stash drop
```

Then resort the merge conflicts using git status, and finally "git add/commit/push". It works, but I would prefer a simpler solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Git is warning you that you have changes you will lose if you did a `pull`. If you don't care about those changes, then you can run `git checkout .` or `git reset -- .` to throw them away. If you do want to keep them (And since you say you're using `git stash apply`, it seems that you do), then you need to keep doing what you're doing, or commit your local changes before pulling.

As to whether or not you can configure git to remember this, it seems like the answer is no, and that's probably a good thing; git is trying to stop you from making a mistake you can't recover from.

Comment: I definitely do not want to do "git checkout .". I do want to enter the merge conflict :)

Comment: It's not a conflict; git has aborted the merge because it doesn't want to overwrite your changes

Answer (score 0):

you have o decide what to do with uncommitted changes before you do any merge.

1. you can stash them (to restore them after merge): `git stash`
2. you can abandon them: `git reset -- .`
3. you can commit them then merge `git ci -m "Title"`

simply before a merge `git status` should report that there is no changes to commit.

When you do a `pull` and branch you are working on if forked pull request will have to do a merge. This may lead to conflict which have to be resolved manually (in this case you will have in file those markings: `>>>>>>`, `=====`, `<<<<<`), for example you have to decide which line should go first if to commit have added a new line is same place.